# I can't close a window

Tags: game-engine

I watched a video on how to close a window it worked but when I make a window cover everything I can't close it. This happend when I was trying to make a game and the only way to fix it was to do the project all over again. Can you please show me a way to close it. Or on blender 2.80 make a close button on new windows. And also game-engine was the only tag kind of related to this.

Comment: Can you link the video an share a sample blend file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? As it stands there really isn't enough information in your question to figure out what you are actually doing/ how to fix it.

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain. I was watching a tutorial on how to make a game on blender. I accidentally did something wrong then I made like 5 new windows and I didn't know how to close it I did everything all over again on another project. Then I made the window full screen then somehow when I minimized blender I did something then it was fixed but then the order of the windows were changed a bit. I know it doesn't make sence but I'll just start over again another project.